# Fetching database data based on a condition of certain tables

Tags: reactjs, typescript, postgresql, supabase

So, sorry if the title isn't clear enough (english is not my native language).

I'm using [supabase](https://supabase.com/docs) with [nextjs](https://nextjs.org/docs) and I'm trying to fetch data from my database considering the following things:

- Fetch all categories in the database. (id, name)
- Fetch all the subforums of each categories. (id, name, description)
- Fetch all the threads of each subforum if the `pinned` field is true.
- Getting the general thread's count of a subforum [ignoring pinned field or any other condition].

I've managed to build a query that get the categories, subforums and pinned threads. I can't fullfill both third and fourth condition at the same time. Any attempt of fetching the data results in a null result.

This is my latest attempt:

```
const { data, error } = await supabase
  .from("categories")
  .select("id, name, subforums(id, name, description, threads(id, title))")
  .eq("subforums.threads.pinned", true);
```

The structure of the database is the following:

```
export interface Database {
  public: {
    Tables: {
      categories: {
        Row: {
          created_at: string
          id: number
          name: string
          updated_at: string | null
        }
        Relationships: []
      }
      reply: {
        Row: {
          author_id: string | null
          content: string
          created_at: string
          id: number
          thread_id: number | null
          updated_at: string | null
        }
        Relationships: [
          {
            foreignKeyName: "reply_author_id_fkey"
            columns: ["author_id"]
            referencedRelation: "users"
            referencedColumns: ["id"]
          },
          {
            foreignKeyName: "reply_thread_id_fkey"
            columns: ["thread_id"]
            referencedRelation: "threads"
            referencedColumns: ["id"]
          }
        ]
      }
      subforums: {
        Row: {
          category_id: number
          created_at: string
          description: string
          id: number
          name: string
          updated_at: string | null
        }
        Relationships: [
          {
            foreignKeyName: "subforums_category_id_fkey"
            columns: ["category_id"]
            referencedRelation: "categories"
            referencedColumns: ["id"]
          }
        ]
      }
      threads: {
        Row: {
          author_id: string | null
          content: string
          created_at: string
          id: number
          pinned: boolean
          subforum_id: number | null
          title: string
          updated_at: string | null
        }
        Relationships: [
          {
            foreignKeyName: "threads_author_id_fkey"
            columns: ["author_id"]
            referencedRelation: "users"
            referencedColumns: ["id"]
          },
          {
            foreignKeyName: "threads_subforum_id_fkey"
            columns: ["subforum_id"]
            referencedRelation: "subforums"
            referencedColumns: ["id"]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I appreciate any help! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well I had to use views to actually achieve what I wanted. I couldn't find any solution on the supabase docs so... raw sql was the answer for me. I also couldn't group by with the supabase library so, yeah. I had to use views for that too:

```sql
-- Drop the view if it exists
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS index_data;

-- Create the view
CREATE VIEW index_data AS
SELECT
    c.id AS id,
    c.name AS name,
    JSON_AGG(
        JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
            'id', s.id,
            'name', s.name,
            'description', s.description,
            'pinned_threads', (
                SELECT JSON_AGG(
                    JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
                        'id', t.id,
                        'title', t.title
                    )
                ) 
                FROM threads t
                WHERE t.subforum_id = s.id AND t.pinned = TRUE
            ),
            'threads_count', (
                SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM threads t
                WHERE t.subforum_id = s.id
            ),
            'replies_count', (
                SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM reply r
                WHERE EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1
                    FROM threads t
                    WHERE r.thread_id = t.id AND t.subforum_id = s.id
                )
            )
        )
    ) AS subforums
FROM categories c
LEFT JOIN subforums s ON c.id = s.category_id
GROUP BY c.id, c.name;
```